# Name for addition and multiplication of a sequence of digits, using varying order of mathematical symbols, with the same outcome

Tags: arithmetic

I am looking for the correct name for mathematics like this:

$$
1 + 2 \times 3 + 4 \times 5 + 6 \times 7 + 8 = 77
$$
$$
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 \times 8 = 77
$$
$$
1 \times 2 \times 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 \times 8 = 77
$$

That is to say: maths that uses the same digits, in sequence, but with varying mathematical symbols, in order to reach the same integer.

For clarification:

- The sum doesn't need to be 77, that just an example.
- Only addition and multiplication are used<sup>1</sup>
- It could be less digits (e.g. just using 1, 2, 3, and 4)
- It could be all digits (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)<sup>2</sup>

Anyway, I'd like to learn/read more about things like this, but I have no idea what to look for.

So... **How are these kind of calculations called?**

---

Until a name for these equations comes to light, I will name them after myself:

## Peachey Equations

To calculate them, I have created [the Peachey Equation Generator](https://gist.pother.ca/650622174093f7d07e3ef8849e908f8c)

---

<sup>1</sup> if there is a term, but *only* if division and subtraction are included, then that's okay too...

<sup>2</sup> Not sure if/where zero fits in here...

Comment: Although it is impossible to say something about the entire universe of mathematical literature, I do not think there exists any name for this phenomenon nor any literature on this phenomenon.

Comment: Math riddle? Coincidence?

Comment: If no name seems to be present... Should I just name them? Call "Potherca Sequence" or something? 

Comment: I decided to name them "Peachey Equations" also available: a Peachey Equation generator: https://gist.pother.ca/650622174093f7d07e3ef8849e908f8c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}$

Following on from Milten's answer, we can consider expressions like these over a sequence of integers $(a_n)$. In particular we have a formula for the means $\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots$, where $\mu_n$ is defined as the arithmetic mean of all the expressions of the form $a_1\ast a_2\ast\cdots\ast a_n$ where each $\ast$ stands for $+$ or $\times$, namely
$$\mu_n=\frac{h(n)}{2^{n-1}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}$$
where
$$h(n)=\prod_{k=1}^na_k+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^k\left(\prod_{r=k+1}^na_r\right).$$
For $(a_n)=(n)$, this formula gives us an asymptotic formula for $\mu_n$. We have
$$\mu_n\sim(e^2+1)\frac{n!}{2^n}.$$
To show this we will consider the sequence $(S_n)$ given by the sum of all the expressions $a_1\ast a_2\ast\cdots\ast a_n$, e.g. $S_1=a_1$, $S_2=(a_1+a_2)+(a_1\times a_2)$, etc. Note $\mu_n=S_n/2^{n-1}$.

We can find a recursive formula for $S_n$ by considering the possible forms of $a_1\ast a_2\ast\cdots\ast a_n$. In particular, we are summing expressions of the form:
\begin{align*}
1~\colon~&a_1\ast a_2\ast\cdots\ast a_{n-1}+a_n\\
2~\colon~&a_1\ast a_2\ast\cdots\ast a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}\times a_n\\
3~\colon~&a_1\ast a_2\ast\cdots\ast a_{n-3}+a_{n-2}\times a_{n-1}\times a_n\\
\vdots\\
n-1~:~&a_1+a_2\times\cdots\times a_n\\
n~:~&a_1\times\cdots\times a_n
\end{align*}
The sum of all the expressions of form $1$ is $S_{n-1}+2^{n-2}a_n$ because there are $2^{n-2}$ expressions of form $1$, likewise the sum of all the expressions of form $2$ is $S_{n-2}+2^{n-3}a_{n-1}a_n$, and so on until the expressions of form $n$ whose sum is $a_1a_2\cdots a_n$. It follows that
$$S_n=\prod_{k=1}^na_k+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(S_{n-k}+2^{n-1-k}\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}a_{n-r}\right).$$
Reversing the order of summation and re-indexing the product inside the sum we get
\begin{align*}
S_n&=\prod_{k=1}^na_k+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(S_k+2^{k-1}\prod_{r=k+1}^na_r\right)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^na_k+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(2^k\prod_{r=k+1}^na_r\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}S_k\\
&=h(n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}S_k.
\end{align*}
Where $h(n)$ is defined as above. Repeated applications of this recurrence yield a formula for $S_n$,
$$S_n=h(n)+2^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}$$
and so
$$\mu_n=\frac{h(n)}{2^{n-1}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}.$$
If $(a_n)$ is such that $a_n\geq n$ for all $n\geq 1$, we can obtain an asymptotic formula for $\mu_n$, in particular I claim that
$$\mu_n\sim\frac{h(n)}{2^{n-1}}.$$
To show this, we must show that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}\right)=0.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
h(n)&=\prod_{k=1}^na_k+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^k\left(\prod_{r=k+1}^na_r\right)\\
&=a_n\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^k\left(\prod_{r=k+1}^{n-1}a_r\right)\right)\\
&=a_n\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}2^k\left(\prod_{r=k+1}^{n-1}a_r\right)+2^{n-2}\right)\\
&=a_n\left(h(n-1)+2^{n-2}\right)\\
&\geq a_nh(n-1).
\end{align*}
We have $a_n\geq n$ for all $n\geq1$ and hence
\begin{align*}
h(n)&\geq nh(n-1)\\
&\geq n(n-1)h(n-2)\\
&~~\vdots\\
&\geq n(n-1)\cdots(k+1)h(k)\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!}h(k).
\end{align*}
From which it follows
$$\frac{h(k)}{h(n)}\leq\frac{k!}{n!}$$
and so for all $n\geq2$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}&\leq \frac{2^{n-1}}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k!}{2^k}\\
&=\frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{k!}{2^k}\right)\\
&\leq \frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{(n-2)!}{2^{n-2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}\right)\\
&\leq\frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}+1\right)\\
&=\frac{3}{n}.
\end{align*}
The third line is justified by the fact that $k!/2^k$ is monotonically increasing.
Hence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}\right)=0$$
and
$$\mu_n\sim\frac{h(n)}{2^{n-1}}.$$
Since $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive integers, we can write
$$h(n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2^k}{\prod_{r=1}^ka_r}\right)\prod_{k=1}^na_k.$$
The sum in this expression for $h(n)$ converges because every term is positive and
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2^k}{\prod_{r=1}^ka_r}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2^k}{k!}\leq e^2-1.$$
Thus
$$h(n)\sim\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{\prod_{r=1}^ka_r}\right)\prod_{k=1}^na_k$$
and
$$\mu_n\sim\left(2+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{\prod_{r=1}^ka_r}\right)\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^na_k.$$

The following table shows the asymptotic behaviour of $\mu_n$ for various $(a_n)$.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline 
a_n & \sim\mu_n \\ \hline
n & \displaystyle{(e^2+1)\frac{n!}{2^n}} \\ \hline
mn & \displaystyle{(e^{2/m}+1)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^nn!} \\ \hline
2n-1 & \displaystyle{\left(1+e\sqrt{\pi}\erf(1)\right)\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!}} \\\hline
2^n & \displaystyle{\approx(3.64163)2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} \\\hline
2^{n^2} & \displaystyle{\approx(3.12549)2^\frac{(2n+5)n(n-1)}{6}} \\\hline
n^2 & \displaystyle{\approx(5.25235)\frac{n!^2}{2^n}} \\\hline
n^{11} & \displaystyle{\approx(4.00195)\frac{n!^{11}}{2^n}} \\\hline
F_n & \displaystyle{\approx(19.6833)\frac{\varphi^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}{(2\sqrt{5})^n}} \\\hline
1 & \displaystyle{\frac{n+1}{2}\quad(\textrm{Exact})} \\\hline
2 & \displaystyle{\frac{n^2+5n+2}{4}\quad(\textrm{Exact})} \\\hline
\end{array}$$
Note $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number and $\varphi$ is the golden ratio. Since $F_2< 2$, we cannot immediately use the asymptotic formula above, the trick is to use the law of total expectation to find that $\mu_n=\mu_{n-1}^*+1/2$, where $\mu_n^*$ is the sequence of means associated to $(F_{n+1})$. In the end we find that the asymptotic formula works just the same for $(F_n)$, which shows that the condition given for the asymptotic formula to hold is not a necessary one.

## Remarks

I suspect a similar method to this could be used to determine the behaviour of the variance, at least for some choices of $(a_n)$. I have no idea about determining which values are taken more than once by such expressions, I suppose one might want to consider the primitive cases of this, i.e. $1+2+3=1\times2\times3$ is primitive while $1+2+3+4=1\times2\times3+4$ is not.

## Edit

There is a much stronger result for the asymptotic behaviour of such sequences, namely:

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\infty,$$
then
$$\mu_n\sim h(n)/2^{n-1}.$$
**Proof**

For all $M\in\mathbb{R}$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, $a_n>M$. Let $M>2$, then using the recurrence for $h(n)$ from before, we have for all $n> k\geq N$
\begin{align*}
h(n)&=a_n(h(n-1)+2^{n-2})\\
&\geq Mh(n-1)\\
&~~\vdots\\
&\geq M^{n-k}h(k).
\end{align*}
If $h(n)=0$ then $h(n+1)=a_{n+1}2^{n-1}>0$, so $h(n)\neq0$ for all sufficiently large $n$, thus
$$\frac{h(k)}{h(n)}\leq M^{k-n}.$$
Again for $n$ sufficiently large
\begin{align*}
\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}&\leq\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}+\sum_{k=N+1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}\right)\\
&\leq\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}+2^{n-1}\sum_{k=N+1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{M^{k-n}}{2^k}\right)\\
&\leq \frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{M}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{M}{2}\right)^k\\
&=\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{M}\right)^n\frac{\left(\frac{M}{2}\right)^n-1}{\frac{M}{2}-1}\\
&= \frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}+\frac{1-\left(\frac{2}{M}\right)^n}{M-2}\\
&\leq \frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}+\frac{1}{M-2}.
\end{align*}
The recurrence for $h(n)$ tells us that $2^{n-1}/h(n)\leq2/a_n$, so
$$\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}\leq\frac{2}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}+\frac{1}{M-2}.$$
For sufficiently large $n$,
$$\frac{2}{a_n}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{h(k)}{2^k}\leq\frac{1}{M},$$
and so
$$\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}\leq\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{M-2}.$$
Finally, letting $M\rightarrow\infty$, and hence also $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have the result
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2^{n-1}}{h(n)}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{h(k)}{2^k}\right)=0.$$
If $a_n\neq0$ for all $n\geq1$, we may write
$$\mu_n\sim\left(2+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k}{\prod_{r=1}^ka_r}\right)\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^na_k.$$
Note the sum converges because from some point on $a_n>2$.

The same result probably also holds if $a_n$ can take negative values, but the proof seems a bit finicky and I had limited time.

Comment: Great answer! From what I can see, it doesn’t matter that the $a_n$ are integers, right? Also, I guess we just need $a_n\ge n$, and not really that the sequence is increasing? Or is that wrong?

Comment: @Milten Thanks! $a_n\geq n$ and is the only necessary part for the proof, i'm not sure why I got so hung up on $a_n$ being strictly increasing. Note $a_n\geq n$ is not a necessary condition for the asymptotic formula, $F_n$ for example.

Comment: I guess $F_n\geq n $ for sufficiently large $n$ though, maybe thats a necessary condition.

Comment: Wow. That is awesesome!

Comment: My math skills are limited, but would it be possible to create a single formula out of all of this?

Comment: @Potherca The main formula in this answer would probably be the one given for $\mu_n$ at the very beginning, but with $h(n)$ defined recursively as $h(n)=a_n(h(n-1)+2^{n-2})$ and $h(1)=a_1$. The approximate value of $\mu_n$ is given by the asymptotic formula, I have updated my answer with a more general condition on $a_n$ for which it holds. The asymptotic formula works best for $a_n$ that grow fast, for $a_n=2^{n^2}$, the exact value of $\mu_3$ is $6413$ and the asymptotic formula gives $\approx6401$.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer and assigning the bounty. Great work, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a long comment than an answer.

I don't know about a name, but note that there is nothing special about the digits $1$ to $9$; you can extend the problem to any (multi)set of numbers, e.g., say, $(1, 2, \ldots, 15)$ or $(0,4,4,-2)$.

For my own curiosity, I've made some histograms of the number of of ways to get each result. I'm using the set $(1, \ldots, N-1)$ ("minus one" because I messed up the plot titles haha) and plotting on a log scale on the $x$-axis (with 50 bins). It seems to be approaching some normal-ish distribution in the limit. Interesting topics could be finding the mean/mode/variance etc. of this distribution. I'm sure some heuristic arguments could get nice results.

[image]

Comment: The only significance of the digits 1-9 is to limit the scale/scope of possible equation to a fixed set. This allows calculating tall possible equations, instead of having an open-ended formula which I would not be able to create with my limited math skills.

Comment: I've assigned the bounty to @freddie, just for the shear amount of work and explanation. Hope you don't mind.